# All-pass models in practice

Tags: time-series, arima

I am new to time series and I read some paper about all-pass models.

An all-pass time series model is "an autoregressive-moving average model in which all roots of the autoregressive polynomial are reciprocals of roots of the moving average polynomial and vice versa".

The mathematics behind are the same as ARMA & such but in practice, in which situation these kind of models are pertinent ?

Here are 2 useful references:

- [Slides](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~rdavis/lectures/ima01.pdf) by Richard A Davis;
- ["Least absolute deviation estimation for all-pass time series models"](http://ftp.stat.colostate.edu/statresearch/stattechreports/Technical%20Reports/1999/99-7%20Davis%20Trindade.pdf) by Breidt et al.

Comment: What is the definition of an all-pass model? Could you give a reference to the paper your read or any other useful material on all-pass models?

Comment: @RichardHardy I added 2 interesting articles

Comment: Great! But could you also write a paragraph on these all-pass models, so that your post would be self-contained? Just copy the first sentence of the abstract of your second reference. That would be helpful and could motivate some users to write an answer. (E.g. I am not quite sure I want to dig into the references to find out what is going on. Before I start, I would rather read a summary that is readily available in the body of the post. Some other users might have similar preferences.)